# HoverIntent does not timout correctly

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, timeout, hoverintent

I've a problem with hoverIntent (JQuery and JavaScript Plugin).

The dropdown menu on my page is sliding up too quick so users maybe can't hover quick enough to the other menu points. For avoid it I want to use hoverIntent to timeout the hiding of the second menu.

My code is:

```
function lvdropdown(){
  var config = {
    timeout: 1000
  }
    jq("#topmenu ul.menu ul").css({display: "none"});
    jq("#topmenu ul.menu li").hoverIntent(function(){
      jq(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility:"visible", display: "none"}).show('fast');
        },function(){
          jq(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility:"hidden"});
    }, config);
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(jq){                    
    lvdropdown();
});
```

I also read that the CSS-File can be the reason for my problem so I will also post the CSS-Style part of my menu:

```
#topmenu ul.menu, #topmenu ul.menu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style-position:outside;
    position:relative;
    line-height:1.5em; 
    z-index:999;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
#topmenu ul.menu li, #topmenu ul.menu ul li {
    list-style:none;
}
#topmenu ul.menu {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#topmenu ul.menu li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#topmenu ul.menu li a, #topmenu ul.menu li span.separator {
    display:block;
    padding:5px 15px;   /* height of level1 links */
    text-decoration:none;
    vertical-align:middle;
    min-height:24px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
    /***** IMAGES *****/
#topmenu ul.menu li a img { 
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
#topmenu ul.menu li a span {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

    /***** FONT SIZE *****/
#topmenu ul.menu li a, 
#topmenu ul.menu li span.separator,
#topmenu ul.menu li a span {
    font-size:14px;
}
#topmenu ul.menu li ul li a, 
#topmenu ul.menu li ul li span.separator,
#topmenu ul.menu li ul li a span {
    font-size:12px;
}
#topmenu ul.menu li ul li {
    border:0 !important;
}

#topmenu ul.menu li.parent a, #topmenu ul.menu li.parent span.separator {
    background-image: url(../images/menu-parent-smooth.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
#topmenu ul.menu li.parent a:hover, #topmenu ul.menu li.parent span.separator:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/menu-parent-hover-smooth.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
#topmenu ul.menu li#current.parent a, #topmenu ul.menu li#current.parent span.separator {
    background-image: url(../images/menu-parent-hover-smooth.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    padding-right: 30px;
}


    /***** LEVEL 2 *****/

#topmenu ul.menu ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:3em;        /* double line height of level 1 ul */
    display:none;
    padding:3px;    /* border of level2 ul */
    width:214px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#topmenu ul.menu ul li {
    margin:2px;
    width:210px;
}
#topmenu ul.menu li ul li a, #topmenu ul.menu li ul li span.separator {
    float:left;
    padding:4px 8px 4px 8px !important; /* height of level2 links */
    height:auto;
    width:194px;
    background: none !important;
}
#topmenu ul.menu li ul li a:hover {
    background: none !important;
}

#topmenu ul.menu li ul li.parent {
    background-image: url(../images/menulili_parent.gif) !important;
    background-position: right !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
#topmenu ul.menu li ul li.parent:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/menulili_parent_hover.gif) !important;
    background-position: right !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
#topmenu ul.menu li li.parent a, #topmenu ul.menu li li.parent span.separator,
#topmenu ul.menu li li.parent a:hover, #topmenu ul.menu li li.parent span.separator:hover,
#topmenu ul.menu li li#current.parent a, #topmenu ul.menu li li#current.parent span.separator {
    padding-right:8px !important;
}

#topmenu ul.menu ul ul{
    top:auto;
}   
#topmenu ul.menu li ul ul {
    left:190px;
    margin:0px 0 0 10px;
}
#topmenu ul.menu li:hover ul ul, #topmenu ul.menu li:hover ul ul ul, #topmenu ul.menu li:hover ul ul ul ul ,
#topmenu ul.menu li.hover ul ul, #topmenu ul.menu li.hover ul ul ul, #topmenu ul.menu li.hover ul ul ul ul{
    display:none;
}
#topmenu ul.menu li:hover ul, #topmenu ul.menu li li:hover ul, #topmenu ul.menu li li li:hover ul, #topmenu ul.menu li li li li:hover ul,
#topmenu ul.menu li.hover ul, #topmenu ul.menu li li.hover ul, #topmenu ul.menu li li li.hover ul, #topmenu ul.menu li li li li.hover ul{
    display:block;
```

Ich hope you can help me with my problem and thanks for read and take your time for help.

UPDATE: 
I tried to set interval on 2000 (ms) and it didn't show any reaction, maybe this helps out too.

UPDATE:

Here I will add the HTML-Structure. The Items are included by Joomla:

```
<div id="#topmenu">
<ul class="nav menu nav-pills">
<li class="item-101 current active">Home </li>
<li class="item-108 deeper parent">Unser Seminar 
    <ul style="visibility: hidden;" class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li class="item-109">Seminarleitung </li>
        <li class="item-118">Verwaltung </li>
        <li class="item-119">Fachleiter/-innen und Mitwirker/-innen </li>
        <li class="item-120">Ausbilder/-innen Fachpraxislehrkräfte </li>
        <li class="item-122">Personalrat der Referendare </li>
        <li class="item-123">Vertrauensvolle Beratung </li>
        <li class="item-124">Förderverein Alumni </li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="item-125 deeper parent">Ausbildung 
    <ul style="visibility: hidden;" class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li class="item-126 deeper parent"> </li>
        <li class="item-136">Die IHK </li>
        <li class="item-137">Fachpraxis-Lehrkräfte </li>
        <li class="item-138">Quereinsteiger/innen </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Change the value `timeout:1000` to whatever you want `1000` is 1 second, `2000` is 2 etc.

Comment: I tried it also with 10'000 (so 10 seconds) but there isn't any timeout

Answer (score 0):

OK - i have reformatted your code, changing the timeout now should work.  I had to guess at the HTML structure but It illustrates the point.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#topmenu ul.menu ul").css({
        display: "none"
    });
    jQuery("#topmenu ul.menu li").hoverIntent({
        over: function () {
            jQuery(this).find('ul:first').show('fast');
        },
        out: function () {
            jQuery(this).find('ul:first').hide();
        },
        timeout: 2000
    });
});
```

Edit:

You're HTML was interfering wiht the styles so if you remove `style="visibility: hidden;"` from `<ul style="visibility: hidden;" class="nav-child unstyled small">` and also change the `id` of `topmenu` to `id="topmenu"` instead of `id="#topmenu"` it should all work.

You could also get rid of this:

```
    jQuery("#topmenu ul.menu ul").css({
        display: "none"
    });
```

By replacing that with CSS of the same selector like this (as they do the same function but CSS loads first you don't want a FOUC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOUC):

```
#topmenu  ul.menu ul{
    display:none;
}
```

In the demo I have added a background color and limited the width of the menu so you can see when you are mousing `out`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/555X7/1/

Comment: I tried your code but now it doesn't even appears the drop down menu (the main menu yes) on the page. Maybe you know the structure of Joomla's menus. For a project I have to work with the CMS Joomla, maybe this helps out too?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the structure of Joomlas menus.  Perhaps you can copy the HTML of the menus and post it here for us to have a look, or even better make a fiddle.

Comment: I added the HTML now.

Comment: really thanks a lot for helping me. The HTML was the structure of the HTML joomla inserted. The problem is that the it's an module which is produced my PHP so the HTML is what the PHP process for my menu.
I will send the link http://seminar.bbs2leer.de 
Maybe this helps better, because to try it out like this didn't help in the end, I'm sorry for make more problems